# How to use AjaxOptions and htmlattributes together in Html.Beginform

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I can have only

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Method", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions{LoadingElementId = "ajaxLoaderBig" }))
```

Or

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Method", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new {@class = "class", @id = "id1"}))
```

how to achieve

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Method", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions{LoadingElementId = "ajaxLoaderBig" }, new {@class = "class", @id = "id1"}))
```

I just want to add a loading element to html.beginform for that AjaxOption is used

Comment: `AjaxOptions` applies to `Ajax.BeginForm()`,  not `Html.BeginFom()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Ajax.BeginForm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#Anchor_19):

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Method", "Controller", null, new AjaxOptions() { LoadingElementId = "ajaxLoaderBig" },  new {@class = "class", @id = "id1"}))
```

Comment: There is no such overload

Comment: do you mean `routeValues` missing?

Comment: Yes,- [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.AjaxHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxOptions%29) - use `null` for the 3rd parameter